# Retrieve user friends media in instgram API

Tags: media, instagram, instagram-api

How to retrieve user friends media in Instagram?

There is no implementation to do this in Instagram documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use multiple endpoints to do this.

- Get a list of an authenticated user's followers: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_followed_by
- Get a list of users followed by the authenticated user: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#get_users_follows
- Loop through followed by and followers and get media for each user: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

You will only get media for users with public profiles.

Comment: sooo their api is way worse than twitters? on twitter i can define callbacks that get executed i.e whenever a new tweet with #trump is posted (ofc with limits too) so i take it no such thing exists for ig, right?